# How do I add fields to log4j2's JSON logs

Tags: java, json, log4j2

Say I have a standard JSON log as in the example in the docs (below)

```
{
    "logger":"com.foo.Bar",
    "timestamp":"1376681196470",
    "level":"INFO",
    "thread":"main",
    "message":"Message flushed with immediate flush=true"
}
```

Now I want to add custom info to this log like so:

```
{
    "logger":"com.foo.Bar",
    "timestamp":"1376681196470",
    "level":"INFO",
    "thread":"main",
    "message":"Message flushed with immediate flush=true",
    "extrainformation":"Some very important stuff I need to include",
    "extrainformation2":"Some other very important stuff I need to include"
}
```

Is there a way to do this? The docs don't seem to mention anything about adding properties to the log object. Do I need to make a custom layout or programmatically add fields or what?

[relevant log4j2 docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout)

Comment: I think creating a custom layout plugin is what you need to do. You can format the printed message as you wish with the layout. The rest is a matter of retrieving data from the LogEvent/Message.

Comment: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/extending.html#Layouts

Comment: I was afraid of that. I've never written a plugin. Good time to learn I guess. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @alan7678 said -

A custom layout was also the solution for me.

```
@Plugin(name = "ExtendedJsonLayout", category = Node.CATEGORY, 
    elementType = Layout.ELEMENT_TYPE, printObject = true)
public class ExtendedJsonLayout extends AbstractJacksonLayout {

// Lots of code!
}
```

I created a Log4j2 layout plugin called "extended-jsonlayout". You can include it in your project with Maven or Gradle. Check it out here -

https://github.com/savantly-net/log4j2-extended-jsonlayout

Comment: Can the value of the custom field be dynamic or is the `getMixedFields()` method only called once on application startup?

Comment: `getMixedFields()` is called on each log event, so it can be dynamic. But it could be tricky depending on the context you want to get values from. https://github.com/savantly-net/log4j2-extended-jsonlayout/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/layout/ExtendedJsonLayout.java#L461

Comment: Will it work with log4j2 v2.21?  The README mentioned 2.8 and 2.9.

Answer (score 6):

This can be archived simply via the the config file.

See my log4j2.yaml:

```
Configuration:
  status: warn
  appenders:
    Console:
      name: STDOUT
      JsonLayout:
        complete: false
        compact: true
        eventEol: true
        KeyValuePair:
          -
            key: extrainformation
            value: Some very important stuff I need to include
          -
            key: extrainformation2
            value: Some other very important stuff I need to include

  Loggers:
    Root:
      level: "warn"
      AppenderRef:
        ref: STDOUT
```

Custom fields are always last, in the order they are declared. The values support [lookups](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html)

Comment: How to do this same configuration in Maven ?

Comment: Although the above configuration file is independent of maven or gradle you can find the instructions here: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html#Using_Log4j_in_your_Apache_Maven_build

Comment: What if we don't always need the values? How to conditionally add them. Because by default, they will show up in each logging line.

Comment: I'm not aware of any solutions to the problem via configuration files alone. You probably have to dig into a solution via code. But are you sure thats a valid use case, absolutely necessary and the effort is well spent?

Comment: @MrSpock How to pass a value to this custom field from log statement in the program?

Comment: This solution is mainly related to GELF (https://docs.graylog.org/docs/gelf) logging. You might want to look into Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC) Example: https://www.baeldung.com/mdc-in-log4j-2-logback